# iOS bordered button behaviour on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a pre-iOS UIButton with border in my app. I use:

```
btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

This works ok but on tap the border does not flash(button highlight state). Any way to easily implement this ?

Comment: What's _pre-iOS_? Did you mean pre-iOS 7?

Comment: Do you want touch on highlight flash right? Did you select that button in attribute inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this when creating the button:

```
[self.botonConfigurar addTarget:self action:@selector(setBgColorForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.botonConfigurar addTarget:self action:@selector(clearBgColorForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
[self.botonConfigurar addTarget:self action:@selector(setBgColorForButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

and these 2 functions:

```
-(void)setBgColorForButton:(UIButton*)sender {

    [self.botonConfigurar setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.botonConfigurar.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0 green:194/255.0 blue:237/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

-(void)clearBgColorForButton:(UIButton*)sender {

    [self.botonConfigurar setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.botonConfigurar.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61/255.0 green:169/255.0 blue:222/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;

}
```

Do whatever you want with the button inside these functions.

PD: Make your button a `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`

PD2: In `clearBgColorForButton:sender` write your `UIButton`'s original parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is Just Example

```
 [button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```